# Google Anaytlics v4 Android casting error

Tags: java, android, casting, google-analytics

I Cannot for some reason get the Anaytics simple screen view tracking to work, I have followed all the documentation, however am getting a casting issue:

This is how I am trying to call the code within my onCreate():

```
Tracker t = ((Analytics) getApplication()).getTracker(Analytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("Home");
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

However whenever I try to run it I get a casting error, please see below for my Log error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.Menu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.test.test.Analytics
```

**Edit** - Another attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <screenName name="com.test.test.Menu">
        Analytics Menu
    </screenName>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-1</string> <!-- I have added my actual trackid in my code -->
</resources>

// Then I use this within my Menu.onCreate()
 ((Analytics) getApplication()).getTracker(Analytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

However I am still getting the same casting error stated above

Comment: Did you Create the configuration file? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#analytics-xml  or https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens

Comment: Yes I have the global_tracker.xml, the only thing i changed in there was adding my tracking id into "ga_trackingId"

Comment: I am pretty sure screenName  comes from that not "Home"

Comment: I have updated my questions with a different variation I am trying and have included my current global_tracking.xml

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error has nothing to do with Analytics. Check if you have replaced the Application class in your manifest with com.test.test.Analytics. It seems you are still using the default Android application class.

Comment: I have this line within the manifest - application android:name="com.test.test.Analytics" /> after the closing tag of my main app application